# I want to display the phone number entered by user during signup in the next activity

Tags: android, material-components-android, material-components

i.e when the user enters his/her phone number ,the next activity should say : WE HAVE SENT AN OTP TO YOUR NUMBER ( WHERE INSTEAD OF NUMBER , IT SHOULD DISPLAY THE PHONE NUMBER ENTERED BY USER ) FOR MY ANDROID APP

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I pass data between Activities in Android application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2091465/how-do-i-pass-data-between-activities-in-android-application)

Comment: Hi Ayush! Welcome to StackOverflow! Your question is a little hard to understand without more context. Would you mind editing your question to add more detail on what you've already tried to do and what specific problems you're running into?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

open a new activity and send data through intent like this in your first activity :

```
val intent = Intent(context, MySecondActivity::class.java)
            intent.putExtra("phoneNumber", myPhoneNumber)
            context.startActivity(intent)
```

then in your second activity in onCreate():

```
phoneNumber = intent.extras?.getParcelable("phoneNumber")
```

Comment: is "phoneNumber" the id of the view?

Comment: This is a key for the phonenumber that you want to pass to the second activity and retrieve it there

Comment: Ok, thanks .. and in the next activtity view .. just display android:text="@string/myPhoneNumber" .right? {In the XML file}

Comment: No you need to set it in your activity after retrieving it like: mytextView.text = phoneNumber